# How to set distance between button and its bound?

Tags: android

How do i set the distance shown on the picture below. What attribute do i have to use ?

[image]

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you can use layout_margin, android:paddingBottom

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI layout_margin sets distance between bounds of different views and padding sets it between internals of button and button itself. So they are not what i need.

Comment: Aren't you trying to add more space between the "HELLO" box and the views around it? How is layout_margin is not what you need?

Comment: @Hamed look at my xml file. I have added to it `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` and this is the result: https://snipboard.io/mOpuFy.jpg . As you can see the distance, i told about in my question, didn't Increase so this is not what i need.

Comment: @Hamed i just want to know how to regulate that distance.

Comment: explain question more , so it is easier to understand

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI i want to change the distance i pointed with arrows on the picture in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your question you need distance from top and bottom as pointed arrow,

to achieve this you can use android:insetTop and android:insetBottom property,

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:insetTop="10dp"
        android:insetBottom="10dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```